# How do I get a custom controller to present in view?

Tags: cache, php-5.4, controllers

I'm currently working on a simple process where I've built a controller that lets me know if a person's browser is not running something comparable to the setup I'm putting together. If I go to `http://example.com/useraction/index/checkbrowser` then the code will either return a commented line that reads `<!--- GOOD TO GO --->` or it will return an image and link to encourage the user to upgrade their browser.  I'm doing this through a controller that I have built because it does seem to work as is without all of that caching that Magento does. Let's face it, if I were to do this on the view (even though I would think of this as something that normally SHOULD be on the view) then the proper browser information would not return to the user.

With this in mind I have tried the following:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('/useraction/index/checkbrowser');
echo $this->getChildHtml('/useraction/index/checkbrowser',false);
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/template')->setTemplate('/useraction/index/checkbrowser')->toHtml();
include('/useraction/index/checkbrowser');
```

None of this is working. What am I missing?

Comment: I am a little confused here, surely you could create a block and set it not to cache. Then this block can get the user's browser information no problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run something in controller, you should run it directly in the browser, just enter it as the following: 
http://www.yourdomain.com/useraction/index/checkbrowser/

If you want to call that function in hmtl file, you should put it in a block / helper file. That's much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Create Tbi_Extension.xml in app/etc/modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Tbi_Extension>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Tbi_Extension>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create app/code/local/Tbi/Extension/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Tbi_Extension>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Tbi_Extension>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
    <routers>
        <modules>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Tbi_Extension</module>
                <frontName>extension</frontName>
            </args>
        </extension>
    </routers>  
</frontend>
</config>
```

Create file app/code/local/Tbi/Extension/controllers/YourController.php

```
<?php  class Tbi_Extension_YourController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
       public function showAction(){
          echo 'here';
   }
}
```

When you call now url local/yoursite/extension/your/show message "here" will be displayed

Further you can use :

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

To use your layouts

You can use your whatever result in :

```
 $this->loadLayout();
$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
$this->renderLayout();
```

If you want to show in template then use:

```
echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();
```

Comment: That's most of what I've done. Up until the "Further you can use:" section of the message. I DO want to show the result IN the template, but the code there: `echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();` doesn't refer to the controller I've created. That's what I believe I'm missing.

Comment: I have Updated my answer